# Does adblockers(ublock) protect you from Malvertisement?

Tags: attacks

With malvertisement on the rise, I was wondering if it's as easy to protect yourself from it by just using an adblocker like ublock origin?

Comment: My general advices concerning malvertisement -- aside using a blocker with a good set of default filter lists: 1) Enable click-to-play for plugins (i.e. have Flash applets **not** execute without your explicit permission); 2) [Block all 3rd-party frames](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-Benefits-of-blocking-3rd-party-iframe-tags).

Answer (score 5):

Ublock does in fact completely deny connections, so yes. It should protect you against a lot of malvertisement. Most malvertisements are in the form of flash ads, and these days its smart to keep flash disabled except for when you really need it on trusted websites.